# How could I change Linux command to another key combination?

Tags: command-line

I'm using wmii, so <kbd>Alt</kbd> key Linux command was disabled.

I want to change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>B</kbd>
so that I can use them to jump by word.

But I searched on line, and didn't find anything about change Linux Command key bindings.

How to do it?

Comment: Do you mean the console key bindings or do you want to remap Alt to Ctrl in X for all X applications?

Comment: @Ruslan, Alt key is not available, so I want to transfer some alt key bindings to ctrl key bindings, but can't find any clue on google.

Comment: That's because the GUI on linux based systems is heterogeneous, and you want to do this via your *particular* window manager or desk environment.  So if you search for "how to do it on linux", you won't find anything.  There aren't any "Linux Command key bindings", or at least very few and they aren't dynamic.  Same for X. But your DE or WM probably has oodles and should let you configure them however you want.

Comment: @goldilocks you're wrong. There's DE/WM agnostic `xmodmap(1)`. The OP assumes it's in X.

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, if you want to *remap* Ctrl <-> Alt, absolutely that is a good answer (there's already stuff around if you search for e.g., "linux remap key").

Comment: The question is unclear. I suppose that if you do the remap with XKB (or xmodmap, but XKB is now the way to do), it will also be taken into account by your window manager, which will then "disable" your Ctrl physical key (now seen as Alt). IMHO, what you want to do is to ask each application that use Alt to use Ctrl instead. This may not always possible. And for terminals (if you use them), you don't want to do that because the Ctrl key has its own important use.

Comment: @Ruslan, I guess I may cause some misunderstanding here. I did really bad description here, trying to fix it in a moment.

Comment: @Ruslan Since the problem comes from the WM, which reserves a key for itself, you do *not* want to use a WM agnostic command such as xmodmap, since the WM will also be affected by the X remapping.

Comment: @vinc17 yeah, I've realized this after seeing your answer. That's why I've removed mine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because even after reading the comments, I don't understand what you mean by “Linux command”. I think you're trying to change key bindings in an application, but which application? Given the comments, where you explain your real problem (not being able to use some modifier keys because you're running Linux in a virtual machine), @Ruslan's suggestion of moving the modifier keys to different keyboard keys is probably what you should do to solve your actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

The solution with wmii is to keep the Alt key for applications, and use another key, such as the Windows key, for the wmii command key, as [describe in this wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/wmii#Configuration_Variables).

Comment: 17, the pathetic thing is, I got to use visual box for ubuntu under windows 7, and the damn win + L can't be forbidden.

Comment: 17, But fortunately, I've got a second_way to realize my purpose, ctrl + arrow_left/ arrow_right can do what I want. Thanks for both you and Ruslan.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a little bit complex to change that key binding.

But if you want to jump by word.

You can try use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>arrow_left</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>arrow_right</kbd>

It would do what you want.

Comment: I assume that you're using Emacs here. Note that for the other key sequences using the Meta (Alt) key, you can also use the ESC key instead (they are synonymous in Emacs). But you may have similar problems with other applications that need the Alt key (mod1) for their shortcuts. I suggest that you change the wmii command key from mod1 to mod4 (AFAIK, mod1 is often used by applications, which is not the case of mod4), as described in the wiki (see my answer). You'll have to find which key corresponds to mod4 (Windows key?).

Comment: @vinc17, I use vim.

Comment: yes, esc works, but it's not convenient enough, so far from my fingers

Comment: @vinc17, before I use win key for modkey, but the win+L lock screen issue is nearly unsolvable. So I changed to alt key.

Comment: I didn't know that vim had the same (or similar) bindings as Emacs. I agree that the ESC key is less convenient, but this is good to know as it can sometimes be useful (e.g. when connecting via SSH from terminals that won't have a Meta/Alt key).

Comment: Concerning the win+L lock screen, I don't understand why this is a problem. Do you mean that wmii also needs Command+L for another use? In this case, the right solution would be to disable win+L (I wonder where this comes from), or use a different key sequence.

Comment: @vinc17, disabling win + L is a disaster, tried 3 hours there, including manually edit registry info, all failed, windows = robber's system, but I got use it at company...

Comment: @vinc17, Mod + L to switch to the right window in wmii.

Comment: @vinc17 no, by default vim doesn't have similar bindings as Emacs. But there's [vimacs](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=300), which attempts to fix lack of such feature.

Comment: @Zen how did _you_ make vim use Emacs bindings?

Comment: @Zen I don't understand. Linux doesn't have registry info.

Comment: @vinc17, I'm using Ubuntu in Virtual box under Windows 7.